# I need to use a variable from the main class into another class created by me

Tags: java, class, variables

I was creating a text-based game in java. In this game I created a variable called "name", this variable has a String input from the user.

```
System.out.println("You chose to play, welcome to the game!");
      System.out.println("You can choose your name now!");
      System.out.print("My name is --> ");
      input.nextLine(); 
      String name = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Are you sure your name is " + name + "?");
      System.out.println("1. Yes, that is my name. Time to move on...");
      System.out.println("2. No, that isn't my name...");
      int u = 2;
      u = input.nextInt();
        while (u == 2){
          System.out.println("Then let's change your name!");
          System.out.println("What is your new name?");
          input.nextLine(); 
          name = input.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Are you sure your name is " + name + "?");
          System.out.println("1. Yes, that is my name. Time to move on...");
          System.out.println("2. No, that isn't my name...");
          u = input.nextInt();
        }
```

So I want for the variable "name" to be used in the Character class that looks like this.

```
class Character{
  public static void full_stats(){
    System.out.println("This is your name" + name);
  }
}
```

Comment: The proper design would be to have `name` be a field of `Character`. Then you create an instance of `Character` in your Main class and give the `name` field a value through its corresponding setter, passing the user's input as a parameter to the setter.

Comment: Have a name field in your Character class. Then pass the name into the Character constructor. You might want to rename your class to GameChar or something, because this could cause odd bugs if you want to use the normal Character class from java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it now, you can't.

There are two ways I can think of off the top of my head:

declare name as a class level variable:

```
static String name;
public static void main(String[]args ) {
 //.. other code
 name = setYourName();
 //..
 Character.full_stats();
}


class Character{
  public static void full_stats(){
    System.out.println("This is your name" + Main.name);
  }
}
```

Better approach, pass name as a parameter:

```
class Character{
  public static void full_stats(String name){
    System.out.println("This is your name" + name);
  }
}

public static void main(String[]args ) {
 //.. other code
 String name = setYourName();
 //..
 Character.full_stats(name);
}
```

I would recommend, though, to keep as little code in your main method/class as possible. It is only meant to be an entry point, not your entire application.

Also: following standard naming conventions will make your code a lot easier to maintain/follow by people who didn't write it.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that answers my question. Sorry for responding this late I put the question on overflow and left the PC cuz I had to go somewhere.

Comment: @The_Red_Baron if this answers your question, can you mark the answer as 'accepted'?

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to the method

```
class Character{
  public static void full_stats(String name){
    System.out.println("This is your name" + name);
  }
}
```